# Maven errors in eclipse and while running mvn clean install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I imported a project as Maven project I got the below errors in the properties of the application. Can you please let me know why I am getting these errors. Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh2LX.png)

Added to it I get the below error when I run mvn clean install on my project. I have checked my settings.xml file in .m2 folder. Nothing appears to be wrong in it. May I know why this error is coming. Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prWL6.png)

Comment: From the screenshot - do the files exist within the folder?  Did Maven download the files to your local file system?  Try right click on the project -->  Maven --> Update Project...

Comment: Can you share your settings.xml? I suspect you are behind a proxy right?

Comment: It is an issue with Maven version. When I ran the same command with a different version of maven, it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with Maven version. When I ran the same command with a different version (3.x) of maven, it worked :)